# Is grid search method worth for neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, grid-search

I have tried successfully to apply GridSearch Method to find the best parameters of a SVM and now I would like to apply it to neural networks (`MLPClassifier`)to find the best architecture (i.e. number of layers and of neurons/layer), the best activation function,...

However, I was wondering if this was not going to be too computationnally costly ? Moreover, how should I define my "grid" for the number of layers and of neurons ? Has this already been tested ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a number of layers and neurons considered to be a part of hyper parameters.

In my opinion, grid search is not the best option for neural networks because of [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). People usually consider simple [random search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_search), especially at the earlier stages of the development. It works because quite often some hyper parameters do not affect loss function a lot, so there is no point in exhaustive searching through all possible combinations.

So, I would suggest the following loop:

1. Determine reasonable set of hyperparameters values (lower/upper bounds, steps)
2. Start random sampling for different combinations
3. After some time you will be able (hopefully) **to narrow** search space
4. Repeat with new bounds

In some special cases, you can use gradient based and Bayesian optimizations, but these options are very problem specific.

Comment: I was indeed afraid that the curse of dimensionality was a brake for the application of the method... A critical point is still to define the bounds... Should the activation function be "searched" too or are there rules of thumb about it ?

Comment: @MysteryGuy I'm not sure that it's really useful to explore activation functions. tanh and relu are quite default options.But why not, maybe in your case it's really important. :)

Comment: @MysteryGuy Bounds are difficult, that's true. But I think it's rather easy to determine some *reasonable* bounds with 3-5 manual experiments.